# Flutter: Saving the state of a page even after navigating between screens

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, navigation, state-management

I have a simple thing to achieve. I have 2 screens in my app, on the main screen i have a button which navigates me to a new page called Interests. The Interests page is a list of checkboxes(for which i have to use listview.builder only) and a button to submit the data(which navigates me back to the main screen). The thing i want to achieve is this:

1. checkboxes should work properly.
2. when i navigate from Interests page to the main page and again navigate back to the Interests page, the selected checkboxes should remain checked. In short the state of the page should be saved.
3. I have written a function "applyInterestChanges" to save the data in database. I have to retrieve the same data to display the selected checkboxes(which we were doing by passing the data via constructor).

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Interests(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text("Click here!!"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Interests extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<dynamic> selectedList;
  final void Function(List<dynamic>) callback;

  Interests(this.selectedList, this.callback);

  @override
  _InterestsState createState() => _InterestsState();
}

class _InterestsState extends State<Interests> {
  Map<String, dynamic> _categories = {
    "responseCode": "1",
    "responseText": "List categories.",
    "responseBody": [
      {"category_id": "1", "category_name": "Movies"},
      {"category_id": "2", "category_name": "Sports"},
      {"category_id": "3", "category_name": "Food"},
      {"category_id": "4", "category_name": "Music"},
      {"category_id": "5", "category_name": "Others"},
    ],
    "responseTotalResult": 5
  };

  void _onCategorySelected(bool selected, categoryName) {
    if (selected == true) {
      setState(() {
        widget.selectedList.add(categoryName);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        widget.selectedList.remove(categoryName);
      });
    }
    widget.callback(widget.selectedList);
  }

  applyInterestChanges() { //function to save the changes in database.
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('my_users')
        .document(currentUserModel.id)
        .updateData({
      "interests": widget.selectedList,
    });
  } //this code is working properly. Need to similar function to retrieve the data and display the updated interests list.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Interests"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Select your interests: ",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _categories['responseTotalResult'],
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  value: widget.selectedList.contains(
                      _categories['responseBody'][index]['category_name']),
                  onChanged: (bool selected) {
                    _onCategorySelected(selected,
                        _categories['responseBody'][index]['category_name']);
                  },
                  title:
                      Text(_categories['responseBody'][index]['category_name']),
                );
              },
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                applyInterestChanges();
              },
              child: Text("Submit"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an empty list from the parent widget `MyHomeWidget` & update this list via callback from the `Interests` widget.

Next time, whenever you go back & navigate again to `Interests` widget, we will pass this updated list which saves the state of `Interests` widget. Hence, the checkboxes will be checked depending upon their values in the list.

Here is the implementation:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<dynamic> selectedList = [];
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Interests(
                    selectedList,
                    (List<dynamic> updatedList) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedList = updatedList;
                      });
                    }
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Text("Click here!!"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Interests extends StatefulWidget {
  Interests(this.selectedList, this.callback);
  
  // Passing the list from parent widget i.e, MyHomeWidget
  // Initially the list will be empty
  // We will update the list in parent whenever checkboxes change
  final List<dynamic> selectedList;
  
  // Creating a callback function to save state(update list) in 
  // MyHomeWidget
  final void Function(List<dynamic>) callback;
  
  @override
  _InterestsState createState() => _InterestsState();
}

class _InterestsState extends State<Interests> {
  
  Map<String, dynamic> _categories = {
    "responseCode": "1",
    "responseText": "List categories.",
    "responseBody": [
      {"category_id": "1", "category_name": "Movies"},
      {"category_id": "2", "category_name": "Sports"},
      {"category_id": "3", "category_name": "Food"},
      {"category_id": "4", "category_name": "Music"},
      {"category_id": "5", "category_name": "Others"},
    ],
    "responseTotalResult": 5
  };

  void _onCategorySelected(bool selected, categoryId) {
    if (selected == true) {
      setState(() {
        widget.selectedList.add(categoryId);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        widget.selectedList.remove(categoryId);
      });
    }
    
    // Callback to save the updated selectedList to MyHomeWidget list
    widget.callback(widget.selectedList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Interests"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Select your interests: ",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: _categories['responseTotalResult'],
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                  value: widget.selectedList.contains(
                      _categories['responseBody'][index]['category_id']),
                  onChanged: (bool selected) {
                    _onCategorySelected(selected,
                        _categories['responseBody'][index]['category_id']);
                  },
                  title:
                      Text(_categories['responseBody'][index]['category_name']),
                );
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text("Go back!!"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the method that you wanted to fetch from `Firebase`. I have used the updated class `FirebaseFirestore`. If you are using the older version of `Firebase`, then simply replace `FirebaseFirestore` with `Firebase`.

```
Future<void> fetchInterestChanges() async { //function to get the changes in database.
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('my_users')
        .document(currentUserModel.id)
        .get();
    
    final updatedList = doc.data();
    print(updatedList);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved the purpose. The trick here is to save the list in MyHomeWidget using the callback function and passing the list from Parent widget. Using a provider would have also served the purpose, right? and which one is the better option considering this scenario.. setstate or Provider?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `Provider` also. But for a small number of widgets like in your case, I think `StatefulWidget` will work fine. `Provider` should be used when you have to access or pass data between deep hierarchy widgets where passing arguments in the constructor is really tedious, repetitive & messy.

Comment: Got it! I do have another query. The above mentioned code is only a piece of a bigger app. I have to store the selected interests in firestore database and use firestore to display the selected interests(which we are currently doing by passing the data via constructor). Can you also share how can we acheive that? Im just updating the code in the question

Comment: i have updated the code and added comments where i have written the function. If you could help me out with this?

Comment: You just need to call the `get` method instead of `update` to fetch data from `Firebase` & parse it. Also, I think you are using an older version of `Firebase` as now, you've to use `FirebaseFirestore.instance` instead of `Firestore.instance`.

Comment: If you face any problems while doing that, just ask another question & send me the link. I will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224615/discussion-between-ankit-singh-and-ravi-singh-lodhi).

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code. Please check. You will have to extract `interests` from this data & display it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You should mixin with class `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to save old widgets, for example: https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter-samples/blob/master/lib/persistent_tabbar/page2.dart.

Or when not work:

1. You must save data checkbox to cache, for example in shared presences, etc.
2. When reopening the page, you call data from the cache
3. And when checked/not resave data to cache